# What is the difference between the three files downloaded on running 'apt-get source {package-name}' ? Which is the actual source code of the package?

Tags: apt, package-management, source-code

These four files/folders were downloaded after I ran `apt-get source bash` to get the source code of the package bash in Ubuntu.

```
- bash-5.0
- bash_5.0-6ubuntu1.1.debian.tar.xz
- bash_5.0-6ubuntu1.1.dsc
- bash_5.0.orig.tar.xz
```

What are these four files? Which of these is the source code of the package bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash_5.0-6ubuntu1.1.dsc` is the source package control file; it [describes the source package](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/dpkg-dev/dsc.5) (it’s a text file, you can view it using your favourite text viewer or editor).

`bash_5.0.orig.tar.xz` contains the upstream source code, *i.e.* the archive you’d get from the Bash project itself (with no packaging).

`bash_5.0-6ubuntu1.1.debian.tar.xz` contains the source package’s `debian` directory, *i.e.* everything that’s added to create the package (metadata, build information, patches...).

`bash-5.0` contains the unpacked source package, *i.e.* the result of extracting both archives and applying any patches contained in the latter archive.